# Autowiring beans

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I've created a few beans for validation of an object:

```
<!-- RES rules engine -->
<bean id="rules-execution-server-engine"
    class="util.res.RuleEngineRESJSE">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="util.res.rulesengine.log" />
</bean> 

  <bean id="rio-object" class="UROImpl">
  </bean>

<bean id="trade-validator-context"
    class="rule.trade.TradeValidationContext">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="rio-object" />
</bean>

<bean id="trade-validator"
    class="validator.RESTradeValidator">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="trade-validator-context" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="validation-rules-helper" />
</bean>

<bean id="validation-rules-helper"
    class="util.res.RESRulesHelperImpl">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="rule.traderules.loc" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="rules-execution-server-engine" />
</bean>
```

I can call and create them through a main method sucessfully.
However I am now trying to integrate this code within my other modules.
The trade-validator bean implements a interface which looks like:

```
public interface IValidator {

public Object validate(Object obj) throws ValidationException;
```

}

I am hoping to call this via the interface:

```
validator.validate(rioObject);
```

However this is causing issues as I cannot instanate the interface and from the XML you can see the actual requires two other beans for it's constructor. I've been looking at the autowired approach. But am still getting to grips with it.

Is there a way to point it towards the bean as being the validator to use? As atm the validator is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to avoid using autowire for bigger deployments and wire the beans yourselves.

BTW, why are you not able to instantiate the trade validator ? What is the error that you are getting?

> However this is causing issues as I cannot instanate the interface and
>   from the XML